# SQL JOIN: add custom constraint in JOIN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select the preferred language if it exists and the default language otherwise.

```
SELECT  a.code,
        case
          when vpi.program_items is not null then vpi.program_items  else vpi2.program_items
        end
FROM              activity a                        
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN v_program_items vpi ON vpi.activity_id = a.id AND vpi.language = 'fr_BE'
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN v_program_items vpi2 ON vpi2.activity_id = a.id AND vpi2.language = 'fr'
WHERE   a.id = 62170
```

The v_program_items table looks as :

```
 - ID      | language|  program_items
 - 62170   | fr      |  Présentation du club et des machines¤Briefing avant le vol¤45 minutes de vol en ULM 
 - 62170   |  fr_BE  |  Un vol en ULM (45 min)
```

I use two JOIN (on the same table) and one CASE/WHEN.
Is it possible to use only one JOIN ?

Comment: You probably should use `COALESCE()` instead of `CASE WHEN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joins you have are fine and perform very well with an index - should be a `UNIQUE` index (or PK):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON v_program_items (activity_id, language);
```

Use [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in the `SELECT` list, like "PM 77-1" suggested in a comment:

```
SELECT a.code, COALESCE(v1.program_items, v2.program_items) AS program_items
FROM   activity a                        
LEFT   JOIN v_program_items v1 ON v1.activity_id = a.id AND v1.language = 'fr_BE'
LEFT   JOIN v_program_items v2 ON v2.activity_id = a.id AND v2.language = 'fr'
WHERE  a.id = 62170;
```

In Postgres 11, and only if your table `v_program_items` is big, consider a covering index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON v_program_items (activity_id, language) INCLUDE (program_items);
```

Related:

- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190151/3684)

Either way, while selecting only a single row (or a few), lowly **correlated subqueries** should be even faster. Simple, too:

```
SELECT a.code
     , COALESCE((SELECT program_items FROM v_program_items WHERE activity_id = a.id AND language = 'fr_BE')
              , (SELECT program_items FROM v_program_items WHERE activity_id = a.id AND language = 'fr')) AS program_items
FROM   activity a
WHERE  a.id = 62170
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine.  If you wanted just one `join`, you could do it as:

```
SELECT a.code, vpi.program_items
FROM activity a LEFT JOIN
     v_program_items vpi
     ON vpi.activity_id = a.id A
WHERE a.id = 62170 AND vp.language in ('fr_BE', 'fr')
ORDER BY (vp.language = 'fr_BE') DESC
FETCH 1 ROW ONLY;
```

It is not clear that this would have better performance, though.